# How to Generating SQL dynamically

Tags: scalikejdbc

I would like  to use this library only for generating sql without executing it. 
Can you please let me see good example how can i use SQLSytax in order just to generate. 
for example   :

val query:String = //Use SQLSyntax

println(query)

res1: select * from TABLE where A = ?

val bindedParameters:List[String] = ....

Comment: if you use Slick, you can create a query there and access its selectStatement (or other kinds of statements) without executing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use #statement and #parameters like this.

```
scala> val q = sql"select * from users where id = ${123}"
q: scalikejdbc.SQL[Nothing,scalikejdbc.NoExtractor] = scalikejdbc.SQLToTraversableImpl@37157995

scala> q.statement
res0: String = select * from users where id = ?

scala> q.parameters
res1: Seq[Any] = List(123)
```